# Why is it important to dispose/close a WCF client proxy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I heard that it's essential to Dispose (or Close) a WCF client proxy even when

- you're not using sessions
- there are no unmanaged resources that need deterministic clean up (e.g. open sockets)

For example, when using a BasicHttpBinding with the default binding configuration, this should be fine even in a popular web page, right?

```
var clt = new MyServiceClient();
clt.PlaceOrder(foo);
// no dispose
```

or

```
var clt = new ChannelFactory<IOrderService>().CreateChannel();
clt.PlaceOrder(foo);
```

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you _could_ let the GC do it for you, but that's just not clean code. You declare it, you free it. Basics that don't seem to be taught anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a ChannelFactory & Opening it is an expensive operation and you should avoid doing it for every call if you care performance.

Your first usecase is not right even with basicHttpBinding because it will potentially create a new channelfactory for each instantation. .NET 3.5 SP1 has introduced some ChannelFactory caching so you might be ok in certain scenarios.

In your 2nd usecase, if you cache and reuse the channelfactory, disposing isn't really nesseaary but keep in mind you/your deployment guy can change the binding @ deployment time and lack of closing/disposing can have a huge impact.

In summary it's always safe to close/dispose and that's why MSDN suggest that.

Answer (score 16):

Its good *practice* to close things (and dispose of them) when you're done with them. (Would you leave a file stream open even though you're through reading/writing to/from it?) Off-hand, I can see a few reasons:

1. The server (can/will) have a limited number of active connections it maintains. The sooner you dispose of your service, the sooner the next client has availability to use that slot. (Why wait for a timeout if you are in-fact through?)
2. Avoid the excess overhead of an inactive connection. Granted resources are "plentiful" these days, but the less overhead you keep the better your performance in the end will be.
3. You reduce the risk of errors/exceptions due to timeout by disposing the client when it's through.
4. By closing it when you're through you're effectively keeping the server logs clean. In the end, even if the client doesn't show it, the server can end up with timeout exceptions showing up in the log due to a dormant connections that weren't taken care of when they should have been.
5. [MSDN says to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx) (Note the 4th bullet in the WCF client objects list).

Just a few of the reasons I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: *Closing* a connection is not the same as *Disposing* of a connection.

Comment: @Kirk: Agreed, but also check to make sure no errors are present, otherwise an Abort should be performed.

Comment: a couple of notes - the filesystem represents unmanaged resources. The proxies in the question do not. The question really is 'why' and because it's tidy or because MSDN says so isn't what I was looking for. Are you saying that Dispose closes an open connection (even for basicHttpBinding) and that's why you should do it? thanks

Comment: @ConfusedNoob: File handling was an analogy, not a comparison. And I mentioned MSDN last because, though it is stated, It's not a "good reason" (but implementations presented by the author(s) of packages are always a good indication as to how you should proceed).

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: In the .NET standard library if a `Close()` method even exists, it is often just an alias for `Dispose()` or vice-versa. This also applies to `ClientBase<TChannel>` which WCF clients are derived from, and the documentation even states that disposing the client closes it. If you want to be correct about handling `IDisposable` objects, you could just always use the `Dispose` method and forget about `Close` altogether, as it's superfluous.

Comment: @ConfusedNoob Proxies can represent unmanaged resources. A socket is unmanaged, so is using MSMQ binding which actually writes your messages into a file.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the type of client.  For example, if you writing an ASP.NET application that calls into the service, then it is a good idea to cache the proxy because its creation is expensive.

This being said, once you are done with any IDisposable resource, you should dispose it so that the object being disposed gets a chance to release resources it's holding on to so that it can be removed from memory.  If an IDisposable object has a Close method, it should be called first.

An excellent article on this fascinating subject can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx